# recovering files with scrambled file names

Tags: filenames, recovery, recover

I have a folder of files with scrambled file names. The file extensions are scrambled too. The folder contains a variety of different file formats. The files are not encrypted.

example: original file name = abcde.pdf 
         scrambled file name = !@#FDZ13

Is there a way to recover the original file names? If not, is there a way to differentiate the file formats (.pdf, .png, ...)? Ultimately, I wish to access and use these files again.

I am working with windows.

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Comment: What exactly are `scrambled` file names?

Comment: @Sosukodo I am not working with any particular language

Comment: @Ingo for example... original file name = abcde.pdf                 scrambled file name = !@#FDZ13

Comment: If you're not working with a programming language, are you sure your question belongs on StackOverflow?

Comment: I am asking this question in general. But I have a lot of files that are scrambled, and I hope to unscramble them using VB.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Wei, in principle, the case is quite easy.

I assume you know the set of file types that can possibly appear there. Let's say we expect there to be DOC, PDF and PNG files.

Then I would go ahead and do the following:

```
- create a subdirectory for every file type you expect
- for each file f
-    for each file type t
-        move f under a nice name with appropriate file extension
         to the subdirectory for file type t
-        try to open the file with the correct application for t
-        continue with next file if it works
-        otherwise continue with next file type
- at this point the directory should contain no files anymore
- move all files from the subdirectories back to this one
- remove the subdirectory.
```

Comment: Is there a way to "try to open the file with the correct application" programmatically?

Comment: I have also tried to open a jpeg with a word editor before. But the resulting txt file was junk. In this case, the file was "successfully" opened. Is there a way to catch this kind of error? I am using vb.net.

Comment: IMHO no, you'll have to look yourself whether it makes sense. Take, for example, XML files. You can open them in a text editor, but then you see it's XML.